# Comparing two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server of this form:

[image]

I would like to join these two tables on the "Name" column (where there are duplicates in both of the tables). I then want to compare every row of the "startNo" column and check if table1.startNo >= table2.startNo and if so I want to add a new column with the UniqueRef of table 2.

The result is above.

It is important that it checks table1.startNo >= table2.startNo for every row in table 2, that is the part I cannot figure out

Comment: Please edit your post to include sample data as *well formatted text*. It makes it easier this way to consume the data and re-create the tables for testing purpose.

Comment: You can join both the tables and use case to determine your UniqueRef column in ur result. Although i didn't get how bb1 comes in ur result for the second row.

Comment: @piyushpankaj as the join will match on "Name" column it will match on the first two, it should then as 2>=2 it pulls in uniqueRef bb1

Comment: Oops your explanation did confused me as "table1.startNo >= table2.startNo for every row" means u r just comparing each row. Please ignore my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all of the number fields are decimals, this will give you the output that you want:

http://rextester.com/BYVC41019

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(UniqueRef VARCHAR(5), Name VARCHAR(10), startNo decimal(2, 1), endNo decimal(2, 1));
CREATE TABLE Table2(UniqueRef VARCHAR(5), Name VARCHAR(10), startNo decimal(2, 1), endNo decimal(2, 1));

INSERT INTO Table1(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('aa1', 'name1', 1, 3);
INSERT INTO Table1(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('aa2', 'name1', 2, 5);
INSERT INTO Table1(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('aa3', 'name2', 5.5, 5);
INSERT INTO Table1(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('aa4', 'name2', 1, 2);

INSERT INTO Table2(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('bb1', 'name1', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO Table2(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('bb2', 'name1', 3, 5);
INSERT INTO Table2(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('bb3', 'name2', 5, 6);
INSERT INTO Table2(UniqueRef, Name, startNo, endNo)VALUES('bb4', 'name2', 6, 8);

SELECT
  T1.UniqueRef
, T1.Name
, T1.startNo
, T1.endNo
, T2.UniqueRef
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2             
              ON T1.Name = T2.Name
             AND T1.startNo >= T2.startNo
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not correct.

As per your requirement

1. joining by Name column
2. compare every row of the "startNo" column and check if table1.startNo >= table2.startNo
3. important that it checks table1.startNo >= table2.startNo for every row in table 2

You given the output table having 3rd row as incorrect.
Note: StartNo of aa3 in first table is 4 and it is greater than start no of bb1 or bb2 in second table.
But you given the result as bb3 against aa3 <-- this is not correct.

Comment: Now you edited the post. sorry for posting after editing.

Comment: I think the answer provided by @Jake outputs the result table provided in the question. But it does not satisfy the requirement 3 as i mentioned above.                                                                                   
                      Requirement 3 -> important that it checks table1.startNo >= table2.startNo for every row in table 2

Comment: Also it will give different rowsets if we change the startno of aa1 and aa2 of fist table to 3 and 6. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subselect for the last column that returns the TOP 1 UniqueRef of Table2 WHERE the table1.startNo >= table2.startNo